# cross compile dll on mac OSX with cmake and mingw

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw

I installed the [bwapi](https://github.com/bwapi/bwapi/releases/download/v4.1.2/BWAPI_412_Setup.exe) via wine on Mac OSX. And I try to compile the ExampleAIModule in it with CMake and MinGW on Mac OSX. The ExampleAIModule is actually a VS2017 project, I write a CMakeLists.txt, ran `cmake CMakeLists.txt && make VERBOSE=1` got some errors. I want to know how to fix my CMakeLists.txt?

The folder structure:

```
BWAPI/ExampleAIModule/CMakeLists.txt
BWAPI/ExampleAIModule/Source/*.cpp *.h
BWAPI/include/*.h
BWAPI/lib/BWAPI.lib
BWAPI/lib/BWAPIClient.lib
```

`make` got errors:

```
Linking CXX shared library libExampleAIModule.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ExampleAIModule.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
i686-w64-mingw32-g++   -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -o libExampleAIModule.dylib -install_name @rpath/libExampleAIModule.dylib CMakeFiles/ExampleAIModule.dir/Source/Dll.cpp.o CMakeFiles/ExampleAIModule.dir/Source/ExampleAIModule.cpp.o  -L/.wine/drive_c/Starcraft/BWAPI/ExampleAIModule/../lib
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: error: rpath/libExampleAIModule.dylib: No such file or directory
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-install_name’
make[2]: *** [libExampleAIModule.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ExampleAIModule.dir/all] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)

################### Variables. ####################
# Change if you want modify path or other values. #
###################################################

set(PROJECT_NAME ExampleAIModule)
# Output Variables
# Folders files
set(CPP_DIR_1 Source)
set(HEADER_DIR_1 Source)

############## Define Project. ###############
# ---- This the main options of project ---- #
##############################################

project(${PROJECT_NAME} CXX)

# Define Release by default.
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
  message(STATUS "Build type not specified: defaulting to release.")
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

# Definition of Macros
add_definitions(
   -DNOMINMAX 
   -D_DEBUG 
   -D_WINDOWS 
   -D_USRDLL 
   -DEXAMPLEAIMODULE_EXPORTS 
   -DUNICODE
   -D_UNICODE
)

################# Flags ################
# Defines Flags for Windows and Linux. #
########################################

if(MSVC)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /W3 /EHsc")
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /W3 /EHsc")
endif(MSVC)
if(NOT MSVC)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
   if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
       set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
   endif()
endif(NOT MSVC)

########### Add by me #############

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++)

include_directories(../include)
link_directories(../lib)

################ Files ################
#   --   Add files to project.   --   #
#######################################

file(GLOB SRC_FILES
    ${CPP_DIR_1}/*.cpp
    ${HEADER_DIR_1}/*.h
)

# Add library to build.
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
   ${SRC_FILES}
)
```

Comment: According to the error message, your compiler doesn't support `-install_name` OSX-specific option. Probably, the compiler is not for OSX.

Comment: I don't know how to tell cmake ignore `-install_name` options.

Comment: If your compiler isn't for host system, that is you want to *cross-compile* the project for other platform, you need to use toolchain file, corresponded to the target platform.

Answer (score 3):

CMake always use toolchains to compile for a specific platform/target, as mentioned [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#introduction). However, for cross-compilation, you need to specify the toolchain file it needs to use. This is done using the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` variable, as explained [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compilinghttps://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling).

The parameters related to the compilation (such as the system name, processor, compiler, etc.) on the target platform shouldn't be in the `CMakeLists.txt` file where you defined your project (using the `project` function).

Instead, you're supposed to set the compilers and other parameters related to cross-compilation in a toolchain file. And you may have a toolchain file for each platform you like to cross-compile for.

This is how your toolchain file may look like, assuming that the compilers are in the path:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32-g++)
```

If your toolchain file has the path `/toolchains/windows.cmake`, you need to pass `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/toolchains/windows.cmake` to `cmake`.

This design keeps your project's `CMakeLists.txt` file toolchain-agnostic.

Comment: I know this is against the rules, but great answer, thanks a lot!